# Comprender foldl y foldr haskell

Tags: haskell

estoy tratando de comprender el funcionamiento interno de foldl y foldr, encontré esta estructura de foldlr:

```
eliminaP :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]

eliminaP n = foldr f [] 
             where f x y | mod x n == 0 = y
                         | otherwise    = x:y
```

la cual llegue a comprender, pero ahora me puse como reto, poder lograr lo mismo usando foldl, intente de varias formas pero no obtuve los resultados que buscaba, en si busco una estructura genérica de foldl y foldr la cual me permita observar su funcionamiento, espero me puedan ayudar.

Desde ya muchas gracias y disculpen las molestias que pudiera llegar a ocasionar. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Las operaciones `fold` son fundamentales, ya no en haskell, sino en todo lenguaje de *programación funcional*. Su funcionamiento consiste en aplicar una función *binaria* a una lista, partiendo de un valor inicial.

Por ejemplo, para sumar una lista de enteros:

```hs
suma = foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 [1..10]
```

`acc` viene de *"acumulador"*. Empieza con el valor 0 y se va sumando a cada uno de los elementos de la lista, empezando por la izquierda. Si desglosamos las operaciones:

```
( ((0 + 1) + 2) ... + 10)
```

Como se vé, las operaciones se hacen de izquierda a derecha, como si estuviéramos "doblando" la lista desde la izquierda (`foldl`).

En caso simétrico:

```hs
suma = foldr (\x acc -> x + acc) 0 [1..10]
```

Observa el cambio de orden de los argumentos.
Desglosado en operaciones:

```
(((((1 + (2 + .... (10 + 0))))
```

En este caso se empiezan las operaciones por la derecha (`foldr`). Basta señalar que, para llegar al último elemento, ha tenido que crear un *stack de operaciones* con todos los elementos anteriores. Si la lista el grande o infinita, no es recomendable usar `foldr` (Mirar variantes como `foldr'`).

La operación `fold` la podemos complicar usando una lista como acumulador (como es tu ejemplo). Algunas equivalencias:

```hs
foldl f [] [1..3] ==  f (f (f [] 1) 2) 3
foldr f [] [1..3] ==  f 1 (f 2 (f 3 []))
```

Para saber cuál de las dos conviene usar, hay que tener en cuenta que las listas siempre se recorren de izquierda a derecha. Acceder al último elemento, como hace `foldr`, es bastante costoso ya que tienes que recorrer todos los elementos previos. Es más eficiente emplear `foldl` ya que hace el recorrido en el orden más propicio. Por contra, al acumular en la lista se invierten los elementos. Si hacemos:

```hs
eliminaP :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
eliminaP n = foldl f [] 
             where f acc x | mod x n == 0 = acc
                           | otherwise    = x:acc
```

Probando se ve que invierte el orden de la lista. Tenemos que aplicar un `reverse`:

```hs
eliminaP :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
eliminaP n = reverse $ foldl f [] 
             where f acc x | mod x n == 0 = acc
                           | otherwise    = x:acc
```

---

**Editado**

Otra forma de ver estas funciones `fold` es implementándolas como funciones recursivas:

```hs
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f acc [] = acc
foldl f acc (x:xs) = foldl f (f acc x) xs

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f acc [] = acc
foldr f acc (x:xs) = f x (foldr f acc xs)
```