# Cantidad de elementos de una lista usando foldl y foldr en Haskell

Tags: haskell

Usando foldl o foldr definir una función tam :: [a]− > Int que devuelve la
cantidad de elementos de una lista dada. Dar un ejemplo en los cuales foldr y
foldl evaluen diferente con los mismos parametros.

No entiendo muy bien el uso de fold sobre listas de elementos cualquiera en Haskell.

Comment: Lo siento en SOes no resolvemos tareas ni exámenes, tal vez si replanteas tu pregunta dando la información necesaria sobre tu problema sea mejor recibida por la comunidad, por favor lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ;)

Comment: Si tu problema es entender el funcionamiento de `fold`, puedes echar un vistazo a la respuesta de esta otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/353069/630

Answer (score 0):

La función `foldr` toma como argumentos una función binaria `(a -> b -> b)`, un valor inicial de tipo `b`, y una lista de elementos de tipo `a`; y devuelve un valor de tipo `b`. Esto es:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

El resultado se obtiene al recorrer la lista `[a]` y aplicarle la función a cada elemento, comenzando por un valor inicial de tipo `b` y usando el resultado para computar el próximo elemento de la lista.

La diferencia entre `foldr` y `foldl` es que la primera función recorre la lista de derecha (*right* en ingés) a izquierda, y la segunda de izquierda (*left* en inglés) a derecha. De ahí su nombre.

Ahora para usar esta función para calcular la cantidad de elementos de una lista, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
tam :: [a] -> Int
tam xs = foldr (\x acc -> acc + 1) 0 xs
```

Esta función `tam` recorre la lista `xs` y aplica la función anónima `(\x acc -> acc + 1)`, que por cada elemento `x` de la lista suma `1` al acumulador `acc`, cuyo valor inicial es `0`. El valor del elemento `x` es ignorado.

También se podría hacer más compacto de la siguiente manera:

```
tam = foldr (\x -> (+) 1) 0
```

En este caso `tam` es una aplicación parcial de la función `foldr` y también recibe una lista como argumento y devuelve la cantidad de elementos. En este ejemplo la función anónima retorna otra función que toma un número como argumento y le suma `1`, esto también es una aplicación parcial de la función `(+)`. El valor de `x` es también ignorado.

En este segundo ejemplo, empezando por el valor inicial 0, la expresión final resulta: `1+1+...+1+0`, tantas veces como elementos tenga la lista.